# Edit Dialog when Application crashes

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if it is possible to edit the dialog which is displayed when an android application has crashed. I want to edit the whole message "'ApplicationName' has stopped"

Comment: You mean change the android's ANR one?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Better design and test your applications properly and make sure that there are no uncaught exceptions. The force close dialog appears when things go bad in your application. You have no way to control it.